# rostopic no longer work

Tags: rostopic, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with ubuntu 14.04 indigo. I was downloading a python program and installed a few dependences like `python3-pandas, python3-yaml, python3-rospkg`. Now, it seems like my `rostopic` doesn't work anymore, when I run it, it shows

```
~$ rostopic 
rostopic: command not found
```

, I tried source the setup files below but rostopic still woudn't work.

```
echo "source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

Following is my env values:

```
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.11:11311
```

I tried to export the following env values, and ran it again but rostopic still didn't work.

```
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/administrator/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=/home/administrator/catkin_ws/devel/share/common-lisp
ROS_DISTRO=indigo
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/indigo/etc/ros
```

Also, when I hit double tab on `ros`, it doesn't show rostopic as an option:

```
~$ ros
rosawesome                    rosdistro_migrate_to_rep_143
rosboost-cfg                  rosdistro_reformat
roscat                        rosed
roscd                         rosinstall
rosco                         roslocate
roscp                         rosls
rosd                          rospd
rosdep                        rospython
rosdep-source                 rosrun
rosdistro_build_cache         rosversion
rosdistro_freeze_source       rosws
rosdistro_migrate_to_rep_141
```

From the above list, it seems like my roslaunch is missing as well.
Did downloading those 3 packages break my ros environment? What can I do to fix it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291708/rostopic-no-longer-work/) by [frodyteen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34681/frodyteen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2018-05-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try to install the rostopic package.
`sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-rostopic ros-indigo-roslaunch`

You can find the installed commands in `ls /opt/ros/indigo/bin`

Source your environment `source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash`

---

Originally posted by [simbha](https://answers.ros.org/users/29493/simbha/) with karma: 241 on 2018-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [frodyteen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34681/frodyteen/) on 2018-05-20**:
it's weired, I was missing whole bunch of ros commands. I ended up reinstall `ros-indigo-desktop-full`. Thanks for the help tho.